# Change WP8 App Background in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am trying to create a class to add the ability to change the wallpaper of my app. This is my class:

```
namespace Wallpaper
{
    class Wallpaper
    {
        public static void SetAppBackground(string imageName)
        {
            var app = Application.Current as App;
            if (app == null)
                return;

            var imageBrush = new ImageBrush
            {
                ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageName, UriKind.Relative))
            };
            app.RootFrame.Background = imageBrush;
        }
    }
}
```

But `app.RootFrame.Background` gives an error `App.RootFrame.get` cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead"`.

EDIT: I want to change the wallpaper of my application when I call the function. imageName = image path.

Comment: Try going:
var applicationPage = app.RootFrame;
applicationPage.Background = imageBrush;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this

```
public static void SetAppBackground(string imageName)
{
    var imageBrush = new ImageBrush
    {
        ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageName, UriKind.Relative))
    };
    App.RootFrame.Background = imageBrush;
}
```

But im not clear what are you trying to do..

Comment: yes, that's why i said its not clear what you are going to do. Please explain in a bit detail. Are you trying to set the background of all the pages at once? or something else?

Comment: Thanks, yes all pages

Comment: Does the image have to be dynamically set, with in the app? may be select from multiple images?

Comment: It works now, just forgot to remove the wallpaper from the xaml file. Thanks a lot